Module.symvers only contain symbols from vmlinux when using Petalinux 2018.3
I am using PetaLinux 2018.3 to generate kernel and rootfs images.
I observe that, after the kernel compilation, Module.symvers file only contains symbol entries from vmlinux. It does not contain any symbols exported from in-the-tree kernel modules. The kernel source code Petalinux 2018.3 is using comes from https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx (specifically the release v2018.3).
If I download the same version of kernel source code and build it directly using "make oldconfig" "make -j6 uImage UIMAGE_LOADADDR=0x8000" and "make modules" then I find all the exported symbols in Module.symvers file. I know Petalinux is just a wrapper of Poky with some extra bblayers for Xilinx-specific targets. I also see that the kernel compilation tasks in Petalinux call "make oldnoconfig", "make -j6 zImage UIMAGE_LOADADDR=0x8000", "make -j6 vmlinux UIMAGE_LOADADDR=0x8000", "make -j6 zImage UIMAGE_LOADADDR=0x8000", and "make modules". Everything looks fine. I don't understand how the contents of Module.symvers are different in these two cases.
I use arch/arm/configs/zynq_xcomm_adv7511_defconfig as the config file in both the cases and Module.symvers files I receive from the two cases.
A snippet of Module.symvers generated from the setup where the kernel was directly compiled.
0xa4a12cec  ipv6_chk_custom_prefix  net/ipv6/ipv6   EXPORT_SYMBOL
0x575ae972  media_entity_pads_init  vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0x55417264  unregister_vt_notifier  vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0xcfc9cf89  debugfs_use_file_finish vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0x2d429fdd  set_anon_super  vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL
0xaf26042f  kmem_cache_alloc    vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL
0x2c33e643  replace_page_cache_page vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0x1381d4f3  net_cls_cgrp_subsys_enabled_key vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0x70523a7a  __cond_resched_softirq  vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL
0x64030a84  ieee80211_wake_queues   net/mac80211/mac80211   EXPORT_SYMBOL
0xbff1c14e  snd_soc_platform_read   vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL

A snippet of Module.symvers generated from the setup where the kernel was compiled using Petalinux.
0x575ae972  media_entity_pads_init  vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0x55417264  unregister_vt_notifier  vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0xcfc9cf89  debugfs_use_file_finish vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0x2d429fdd  set_anon_super  vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL
0xaf26042f  kmem_cache_alloc    vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL
0x2c33e643  replace_page_cache_page vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0x1381d4f3  net_cls_cgrp_subsys_enabled_key vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL
0x70523a7a  __cond_resched_softirq  vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL
0xbff1c14e  snd_soc_platform_read   vmlinux EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL

What makes the kernel compilation different in the case of Petalinux?
